How to infer optional in function?
I want to create an enum type with an extra option and a function to transform this enum into an array of objects.
The problem is that when I have an optional property in the Extra option of ReferentialEnum, I lose it when I try to transform the enum with my function.
The type of the enum and the enum (works the way I want it to):
export type ReferentialEnum<Extra extends Record<string, unknown> = EmptyObject> =
  Record<string, { label : string } & Extra>

export const statusesEnum = {
  ACTIVE : { label : “Active”, color : “success.main”, optional : “test” },
  DEACTIVATED : { label : “Inactive”, color : “error.main” },
} satisfies ReferentialEnum<{ color : string ; optional? : string }>
export type StatusesName = keyof typeof statusesEnum

The function:
export function referentialEnumToReferentialCodeList<
  T extends ReferentialEnum<Record<string, unknown>>,
>(enumObj : T) {
  return Object.entries(enumObj).map(([key, stat]) => ({
    code : key as keyof T,
    ...(stat as T[keyof T]),
  }))
}

The function call:
const statusesReferential = referentialEnumToReferentialCodeList(statusesEnum)

In my IDE, I don't have access to the optional property:
The function call
TS PLAYGROUND

Welcome to SO. Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] that we can copy & paste into our IDEs to clearly see your issue and get to work. It should not be missing declarations (for example EmptyObject), and it should not be syntactically invalid pseudocode (for example you can't use those fancy quotation marks in code the way you're using them). Also, screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions. Otherwise the question risks being closed as needing details.

Please include all relevant code as plaintext in the question itself. Links to code are not sufficient to be a [mre]. Until the code is included here as plaintext, the question risks being closed as needing debugging details.

OK I find an alternative solution.
I replace the optional by | undefined:
ReferentialEnum<{ color : string ; optional? : string }> 
ReferentialEnum<{ color : string ; optional : string | undefined }> 

I would have preferred to keep the :
ReferentialEnum<{ color : string ; optional? : string }> 

Playground
